# Kenward-Roger correction applied to $t$-test in LME

Tags: t-test, degrees-of-freedom, lme4-nlme

Kenward and Roger (1997) proposed an approximation for an $F$-test of fixed effects in a linear mixed-effects model through (1) inflating the estimated variance-covariance matrix of the fixed and random effects and (2) adjusting the degrees of freedom (DF). In their paper they state that, when the approximation is applied to a $t$-test (a special case of the $F$-test), it is "comparatively straightforward and essentially recovers Satterthwaite's (1941) approximation". My understanding is that Satterthwaite's method involves only adjustment of degrees of freedom. My question is, when applying the Kenward-Roger correction to a $t$-test for a fixed effect, would we only need DF adjustment, or would we need correction for both DF and the variance-covariance structure? Thanks!

Comment: It is noteworthy that the [Satterthwaite method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test) *does* adjust the variance: rather than using a pooled variance, it computes a weighted combination of two separate variances.